# How to get JQuery JScrollpane to work on a locally-saved webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I cannot get JScrollpane to work when I save a page containing JScollpane onto my machine.

The problem is easy to reproduce (for Firefox 11.0, IE 8 and Opera) by saving down a copy of the following example page locally and loading the local page into a browser:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

This example works perfectly online, though, and looks great! I really like JScrollpane so am very keen to use it in my website - JScrollpane looks excellent!

Using the Firebug debugger I have tracked the problem down to line 164 of JScrollpane.js (unminified version) as follows:

```
contentHeight = pane[0].scrollHeight;
```

It appears to be a javascript, not a JScrollpane issue. For the local version of the example page (i.e. loaded from a file), the pane[0].scrollHeight appears to reflect the height of the div, not the height of the content that is enclosed within the div. This prevents the vertical scroll bar from initialising in JScrollpane and so the JScrollpane does not scroll.

Does anyone know why the scrollHeight does not work in this case? Please excuse if this is a question with an obvious answer as I'm very new to javascript and JQuery. Is there an easy work-around apart from modifying the JScrollpane javascript file?

I just want to be able to develop a web page containing JScrollpane locally without access to the internet.

Comment: I did a  "git clone https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane" and opened the basic.html example locally... Works fine... Please show us your attempt to implement it with full source code.

Comment: I'm just going to http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html in my browser (Firefox 11.0) and clicking File->Save page as then reloading the page from my local filesystem. The code is identical to that in http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html.

Comment: Like I said - it works with the original source code from github. FF does not save a 1:1 copy of this page. For example the link to the google cdn is converted etc. What is stopping you to use the github code?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I now have it working fine locally. I thought that a browser would always save an exact copy of the webpage when doing a "save page as" so I have learned something today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not save a 1:1 copy of a webpage. For example the link to the google cdn is converted etc.

I did a "git clone github.com/vitch/jScrollPane" and opened the basic.html example locally... Works fine...